# how to get numbers in integer from substring in swift 3?

Tags: ios, string, swift3

Here I am having a string like this `"{\"label\":\"57-175\",\"stock\":0}"` in which I need to get `57` and `175` as integers and in which I need to be compared with array numbers but here after truncating from string I am unable to get in the form of integer and I tried to get integer it returning nil and if I tried to get as string it returning optional(57) or optional(175) for both numbers and the mentioned numbers need to be compared with integers in an array below is my tried code can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

```swift
for item in (self.detailModel?.extensionAttribute?.productStock)! {
    let start = item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)
    print(start)

    let end         = item.index(item.endIndex, offsetBy: -12)
    let range       = start..<end
    let mySubstring = item[range]
    let myString    = String(mySubstring)
    print(myString)

    let stockStart     = item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 18)
    let stockEnd       = item.index(item.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
    let stockRange     = stockStart..<stockEnd
    let stockSubString = item[stockRange]
    let stockString    = String(stockSubString)
    print(stockString)

    if stockString ==  "\"stock\":0" {
        let startSize  = myString?.prefix(2)
        let sizeString = String(describing: startSize)
        print(sizeString)

        let color   = sizeString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
        self.colorNumber = color
        let endSize = myString?.suffix(3)
        let string  = String(describing: endSize)
        print(string)

        let size = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
        self.sizeNumber = size
        print(self.sizeNumber)

        for item in self.configurableArray {
            for (key, array) in item {
                if (self.colorNumber?.contains("\(key)"))! {
                    print(Int(self.sizeNumber!))
                    let farray = array.filter {
                        $0 != Int(self.sizeNumber!) 
                    }
                }

                print(self.colorNumber!)
                print(key)
                print(self.configurableArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's JSON. Bypassing all the good developers rules about unwrapping, you should do something like this: `let jsonStr = "{\"label\":\"57-175\",\"stock\":0}"; let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String:Any]; let labelValue = dict["label"] as! String; let values:[String] = labelValue.components(separatedBy: "-"); let int57 = Int(values[0]); let int175 = Int(values[1]); let intScore = dict["stock"]` instead of all the `index(_, offsetBy:)`

Comment: no @Larme I am getting set of strings in an array as mentioned above for this also I need to do the same thing ?

Comment: the son url for this is http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVMwjZhBIO?indent=2

Comment: You receive JSON, so parse it as JSON. Do not try to parse manually the JSON Stringified with "range of", "replace", "cut/slice". Treat it as an object (Dict in your case). From the URL you gave, it's JSON Stringified inside JSON. Use it as if it were JSON, I gave the sample to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way:

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: Any]
let labelString = jsonDictionary["label"] as! String
let labelNumberArray = labelString.components(separatedBy: "-").map({ Int($0) })
let number1 = labelNumberArray[0]!
let number2 = labelNumberArray[1]!
```

Rather than force unwrapping everything like in the code above, I would recommend using guard or if statements:

```
guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
    let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any],
    let stock = jsonDictionary["stock"] as? NSNumber,
    let labelString = jsonDictionary["label"] as? String else {
    //return or throw expection
}

let labelNumberArray = labelString.components(separatedBy: "-").flatMap({ Int($0) })

guard labelNumberArray.count == 2 else {
    //return or throw expection
}

let labelNumber1 = labelNumberArray[0]
let labelNumber2 = labelNumberArray[1]
let stockNumber = stock.intValue
```